# how to perform onCLick Listener in tablayout in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

Hello there i am making swipeable tablayout with view Pager. Swipe in this fragment is working fine but it does't perform the onclick event.
Swipe is working on TabLayout click is not working ? How to add click listener on TabLayout ? in fragment
HOw i can do that?
here is my code:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(((ProductActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            int position = tab.getPosition();
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    Log.e("Position",String.valueOf(0));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Log.e("Position",String.valueOf(1));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Log.e("Position",String.valueOf(2));
                    break;
                    default:
                        break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}
```

and pagerAdapter is:

```
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,int mNoOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNoOfTabs = mNoOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch(position)
    {

        case 0:
            Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
            return  tab2;
        case 2:
            Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
            return  tab3;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNoOfTabs;
}
```

Comment: attach your viewpager with tablayout.

Comment: tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

Answer (score 0):

In this you have not setup your viewpager with tablayout that's why it not performing onclick.
setup your viewpager with tablayout like this

```
TabLayout  tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

after this it will work

Answer (score 0):

**onCreate**

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
setupViewPager(viewPager);

tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

**Setup View Pager**

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "Tab1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(), "Tab2");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**ViewPagerAdapter**

```
    *class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
//            return null;
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }*
```

this is how you use tabs with fragment. and also create Fragment1() and Fragment2() class